# object of type 'NoneType' has no len() error, cant seem to solve it

Tags: python, json, django, request

So, I have created an api that does some functionality on a post request and sends a response back.
I've tested it in my local machine and it works perfectly as intended. But on the server, it shows this error.

```
[Wed Aug 10 16:11:08.124324 2022] File "/var/www/html/caremigration/careapi/views.py", line 3767, in createSalesOrder
[Wed Aug 10 16:11:08.124324 2022] for i in range(len(request.data.get('materials'))):  
[Wed Aug 10 16:11:08.124328 2022] TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I've provided all the details needed and also proof that it works fine in my local machine. Please help me out.

Views.py

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def createSalesOrder(request):

    ASHOST='*'
    CLIENT='*'
    SYSNR='*'
    USER='*'
    PASSWD='*'
    IT_ITEMS = []
    IT_ITEMS_DESC = []

    if request.method == 'POST':

        try:
            # print(len(request.data.get('materials')))
            for i in range(len(request.data.get('materials'))):
                IT_ITEMS.append({
                    "MATNR": request.data.get('materials')[i]['MAT_desc']['mat_id'],
                    "QUANTITY":float(request.data.get('materials')[i]['quantity']),
                    "UOM":"cm",
                    "RATE":float(request.data.get('materials')[i]['price']),
                    "VALUE":float(request.data.get('materials')[i]['total']),
                    "CURRENCY":"INR"
                })

                IT_ITEMS_DESC.append({
                        "DESC":request.data.get('materials')[i]['MAT_desc']['item']
                })

            # print(IT_ITEMS)

            I_HEADER = {
                "PLANT":request.data.get('plant'),
                "ORD_DATE": datetime.date.today(),
                "SORG":request.data.get('sorg'),
                "DIS_CHNL":request.data.get('distribution_channel'),
                "DIVISION":request.data.get('division'),
                "CUSTOMER":request.data.get('customer_no'),
                "TRANSPORTER":request.data.get('trasnporter'),
                "TRUCK_NUMBER":request.data.get('truck_no'),
                "LR_NUMBER":request.data.get('lr_no'),
                "TRUCK_TYPE":request.data.get('truck_type'),
                "MILK_RUN":request.data.get('milk_run'),
                "PERMIT_NO":request.data.get('permit_no'),
                "PERMIT_DATE":""
                }

            with  connx(ashost=ASHOST, sysnr=SYSNR, client=CLIENT, user=USER, passwd=PASSWD) as conn:
                
                result =  conn.call("ZSS_SALES_ORDER_CREATE",I_HEADER=I_HEADER, IT_ITEMS=IT_ITEMS)
                # print(result)

            command1 = 'INSERT INTO `scrap_master` (`id`, `scrapid`, `internal_order_no`, `plant`, `cust_no`, `cust_name`, `gp_no_permit_no`, `truck_no`, `truck_type`, `gate_pass_no`, `milk_run`, `status`, `message`, `creation_date`, `created_by`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);'   
            values1 = (None, result['E_INVOICE'], request.data.get('internal_sale_order'), I_HEADER['PLANT'], I_HEADER['CUSTOMER'], request.data.get('customer_name'), I_HEADER['PERMIT_NO'], I_HEADER['TRUCK_NUMBER'], I_HEADER['TRUCK_TYPE'], 'None', I_HEADER['MILK_RUN'], 'SUCCESS', 'asd', I_HEADER['ORD_DATE'], 'asd')
            
            mycursor.execute(command1,values1)
            mydb.commit()

            for idx in range(len(IT_ITEMS)):

                command2 = 'INSERT INTO `scrap_details` (`id`, `scrap_id`, `sno`, `mat_code`, `description`, `quantity`, `rate`, `value`, `sgst`, `cgst`, `total`, `creation_date`, `created_by`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);'
                values2 = (None, result['E_INVOICE'], idx+1, IT_ITEMS[idx]['MATNR'], IT_ITEMS_DESC[idx]['DESC'], IT_ITEMS[idx]['QUANTITY'], IT_ITEMS[idx]['RATE'], IT_ITEMS[idx]['VALUE'], '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', datetime.date.today(), 'asd')           
                
                mycursor.execute(command2,values2)
                mydb.commit()


            return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK) 

        except CommunicationError:
            print("Could not connect to server.")
            #raise
        except LogonError:
            print("Could not log in. Wrong credentials?")
            #raise
        except (ABAPApplicationError, ABAPRuntimeError):
            print("An error occurred.")
            #raise
        
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
    
    else:
        return Response({"message":"Bad Request"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Request Object looks like this:

```
{
    "internal_sale_order": "1",
    "plant": "Z100",
    "customer_no": "100538",
    "customer_name": "",
    "distribution_channel": "ZZ",
    "division": "ZZ",
    "sorg": "Z100",
    "lr_no": "",
    "truck_no": "",
    "truck_type": "",
    "milk_run": "",
    "permit_no": "",
    "permit_date": "",
    "trasnporter": "",
    "materials": [
        {
            "si_no": "1",
            "MAT_desc": {
                "item": "Ventilation, complete",
                "matname": "SCRAP-01",
                "mat_id": "SCRAP-01"
            },
            "quantity": "0",
            "MAT_code": "SCRAP-01",
            "description": "",
            "price": "0",
            "total": "0",
            "Mat_name": "",
            "edit": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Response in my local Machine (Before POST):
[image]

Response in my local Machine (Response):
[image]

Comment: I think it should be `request.POST.get('materials')` and everywhere use `POST` or `GET`.

Comment: Hi, I tried using `request.POST.get('materials')` but no use, it shows the same error, furthermore ive tried to use it in my localmachine which produced the same error. Its working somehow with `request.data.get()` but not with `request.POST.get()`. Dont know the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try instead:

```
for i in range(len(request.GET['materials'])):
```

?

Comment: ` [Wed Aug 10 16:43:24.106413 2022] `File "/var/www/html/caremigration/careapi/views.py", line 3767, in createSalesOrder

[Wed Aug 10 16:43:24.106413 2022] for i in range(len(request.GET('materials'))):

[Wed Aug 10 16:43:24.106417 2022] TypeError: 'QueryDict' object is not callable `

Shows this error, but out of curiosity, isnt `request.data.get` doing the same thing?

Comment: Dear answerer at first, `request.GET('materials')` is nothing, it is written as either `request.GET.get('materials')` or `request.GET['materials']`, but in this case the method is POST, so it can be written as `request.POST.get('materials')`

Answer (score 0):

`request.data.get('materials')` returns `None` if the `materials` was not in the POST request. `None` cannot be used with `len()` method so you get an error.

I suggest adding a default in `get()` method call:

```py
for i in range(len(request.data.get('materials', []))):
# ...
```

This will avoid the error if "materials" are missing from the request.

It is up to you to decide if you want to raise an error if the "materials" key is missing from the request.

To sum up, the core of the problem is that you're not passing "materials" in the POST request. You should see why is that. My best advice is to use a debugger and to inspect the request object in the view method. Make sure you're using POST method in your client.

Comment: Thanks for answering, you can see the request json data im using in my question, and "materials" is present in that data. Now the thing I dont understand is that it is working fine when triggered from the UI  but throwing this "materials is None" error when triggering from Django's APIView. The same Django APIView is working fine in my local machine, the only problem is with server's Django APIview.

Comment: Can you double check there aren't any typos and such in the request you're sending? It really looks like something is wrong with the request, not the code.

Comment: I just copy pasted the request, so there's no chance of typos. Its the same request that im using in the local machine as well..